# NameError: name 'paramiko' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, python-3.5, lib

I have to write a code in Python3.5 which requires paramiko. I have faced the "NameError: name 'paramiko' is not defined" in my Ubuntu version  17.10. I had checked the lib path also and it is present.is it "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko"

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print(ssh)
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of your code, and the way you execute it ? Do you use a virtualenv ? Are you sure the code is executed with python 3 (default for Ubuntu 17.10 is python 2) ?

Comment: @gaFF I have added the code for that and using python3.5

Comment: Can you show the full error traceback? If you get a NameError that doesn't mean that the import failed, but there is something else wrong in your code.